# Javascript console.log prints values before they are set

Tags: javascript

If I create the following code block:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
new_list = []
for (i = 0; i < x.length-1; i++) {
    var links = {}
    console.log("first:", links)

    for (j = i+1; j < x.length; j++) {
        links["source"] = i
        links["target"] = j
    }
}
//document.write('<b>End of script.</b>');
</script>
```

The console should, in theory, print {}, {source: 0, target 1}, {source: 0, target: 2}, ... 
In actuality, it prints:

```
"first:" {source: 1, target: 5} Test1.html:7
"first:" {source: 2, target: 5} Test1.html:7
"first:" {source: 3, target: 5} Test1.html:7
"first:" {source: 4, target: 5}
```

Why does this happen? How can 'target' have a value of 5 the first time it is printed? Shouldn't the first printed thing be an empty associative array?

Comment: Seems, that the reason behind it is comma. If you just print `console.log(links);` at same place, then you get the expected result.

Comment: I tried it without the comma and got the same result as with the comma.

Comment: Tried [here](http://jsbin.com/kagagono/1/edit?js,console) and seems to be fine. By the way. I'm trying it in Chrome. Mighte be the reason, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm running it in firefox. I guess it's platform specific.

Comment: Seems to be so. Tried in firefox and got same result as you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

> The console object provides access to the browser's debugging console (e.g. the Web Console in Firefox). The specifics of how it works vary from browser to browser, but there is a de facto set of features that are typically provided.

The `window.console` object (and thus also `window.console.log`) behaviour is not specified in the standard. The "weird" behaviour is not due to your code (which executes exactly as you expect it to), but due to `console.log` delaying evaluation (in your browser at least).

---

Running this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dQB8/

In Firefox30 outputs:

```
"first:" Object { source: 0 } _display:25
"first:" Object { source: 1 } _display:25
"first:" Object { source: 2 } _display:25
"first:" Object { source: 3 } _display:25
"first:" Object { source: 4 } _display:25
```

In IE10 outputs

> File: jsfiddle.net first: [object Object]    "first:"    {
>         [functions]: ,
>         **proto**: { }    }
>
> first: [object Object]    "first:"    {
>         [functions]: ,
>         **proto**: { }    }
>
> first: [object Object]    "first:"    {
>         [functions]: ,
>         **proto**: { }    }
>
> first: [object Object]    "first:"    {
>         [functions]: ,
>         **proto**: { }    }
>
> first: [object Object]    "first:"    {
>         [functions]: ,
>         **proto**: { }    }

(So, in firefox I always get the value of "source", in IE10 Ialways logs an empty object)

Conclusion: Don't rely on `console.log` when using mutable objects : )

Answer (score 0):

This is because though you are printing links first and modifying them later the object gets changed...

Here I tried printing a completely new object same as links at that instant...So even if the links object gets modified the printed object doesn't

```
console.log("first:",JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(links)))
```

Comment: I understand that, but shouldn't it print a snapshot of the object at the time that it's being printed? Is printing asynchronous?

Comment: No. It should print an empty object. And it does print in my example.